# Change loading order of blocks

Tags: performance, videos

I have a block with a video in WordPress, and the images below it are out of order until the video finishes loading. How do I change the loading order so that the images finish loading before the video starts loading? Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: do not use video autoload. just load the preview and let user click to play and only then video'll get loaded

Comment: @Vishwa is there a way to do it with video autoload?

Comment: AFAIK, no.. sorry